# Go main package in two files

Tags: go, scope

In `$GOPATH/src/testapp` I have two files

- `main.go`
- `otherfile.go`

main.go has

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  fmt.Println(SomeFunc())
}
```

otherfile.go has

```
package main

func SomeFunc() string {
  return "a thing"
}
```

When I try to run with `go run main.go`, I get an error

```
./main.go:6: undefined: SomeFunc
```

I thought I could create another file with `package main` and code in `main.go` would have access to its declarations. Why doesn't this work? How would I do something like this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I run `go run *.go` it works.
It also works if I `go build` and then `./testapp`.
Hopefully this question helps someone in the future.

Some comments on this page helped me: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/555